# using script tags for client side templates, why can't i load via src attribute?

Tags: html, templates, client-side-templating

this works fine (am able to access the snippet in the dom by id)

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="todo-item-template">
  <div class="todo-view">
    {blah} {blah}
  </div>
</script>
```

but if i put the template in an external resource, i can't find it in the dom:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="todo-item-template" src="todo-item-template.html">
```

chrome is giving me a warning which i think is irrelevant:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: 
"http://localhost:8000/todo2/todo-stats-template.html".
```

i am running from the filesystem, and/or from `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. any ideas?

Comment: Even if you *did* reference it via `src`, how would you access the content? It won't become `textContent` of the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the server is serving `.html` files as HTML files. You will want to have template files be a different file type, such as `.tpl` and have the server send the appropriate headers.