# Why can't I load custom templates using <script> tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-templates

I have a requirement wherein I need to replace many templates from a library by my custom templates. I do not want to fork the original templates in library.

When I load templates in my index.html page like :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="first-template">
  <div class="view">
    {blah} {blah}
  </div>
</script>
```

It works fine. But I have lots of these and do not want to keep all these in index.html. I tried loading them using `src` attribute, but then they are not loaded.

I tried keeping my templates both as `.html` and `.js`. Both didn't work. Why is it so. Isn't both the way mean to serve the same purpose.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939084/using-script-tags-for-client-side-templates-why-cant-i-load-via-src-attribute) , but the discussion is too short and with no tangible solution.

Can someone explain detailed logic and the solution for this ?

Comment: `<script src="foo.js"></script>` will not insert `foo.js` inside itself when load is done; same way, specifying your template in a `<script>` tag and linking to it in a `<script src>` tag are two very different things. If you marked the question with [tag:angularjs], someone might offer solutions to *that* presumably involving `$templateCache` or `$templateRequest`...

Answer (score 0):

The other question says that the Content-Type header of the response for their files was text/html, which didn't match up with their script tag and thus was ignored by the browser.

Your server needs to serve whatever you request for the template files as the mimetype `text/ng-template`.

Say your templates were `.tpl`, in Apache config or .htaccess you can do:

```
AddContentType tpl text/ng-template
```

To force tpl files to be served with the expected mimetype.

Comment: The other answer also says "If you want to fetch arbitrary content for use in a script, use XMLHttpRequest." AFAIK text/javascript scripts get executed; others are ignored, and there's no way to access the content except by issuing XMLHttpRequest manually. [AngularJS docs on `<script>`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) have no mention of `src` being an option. CoffeeScript does process `<script src>` tags, but it is by searching for them, reading their `src` and then issuing AJAX requests to fetch the contents.